# How can I assign custom field layouts using paragraphs?

Tags: theming, paragraphs

For reference:

```
-modules
--contrib
---ds
--custom
---ds
```

I'm looking to add paragraph layouts using flexbox. I don't see a module specifically for this, so I realize I'm going to have to adapt an existing module.

Right now, I'm trying to add custom layouts in the Display Suite module by adding a template config to ds.layouts.twig with the appropriate html.twig and css files.

My concern is that any edits to these files will be overwritten with updates to the DS module. I tried adding a ds folder in the custom modules folder copying over the ds.layouts.twig file and the appropriate files, but it didn't work as I thought it would.

Does anyone have any recommendations to add layout functionality to paragraphs in which I can write my own layouts using grid/flexbox

Answer (score 0):

I've determined that the Layout API and associated modules are a better way to go for what I'm looking to do.

Thanks for reading this, though!